# Why was "this" used as a non const deprecated in C++

Tags: c++, this, deprecated, this-pointer

Why was `this` deprecated in C++? How is the `this` pointer in C++ different than `this` in Java?

Or is [Wikipedia just wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_%28computer_programming%29#cite_note-C.2B.2B03-1)

> Early versions of C++ would let the this pointer be changed; by doing
>   so a programmer could change which object a method was working on.
>   This feature was eventually deprecated, and now this in C++ is const .

Comment: You might need to check the WP history. I've removed the term "deprecated", as well as the statement that the pointer is `const`.

Comment: Interesting... The wording you quoted from Wikipedia is incorrect. `this` is not `const`. `this` is an rvalue. And when I enter the edit mode in Wikipedia I already see "[[rvalue]]" there (someone edited it apparently), but the main page still says "const".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe your mistake is in how you interpret that line. They're not saying "The this feature was deprecated". Merely the ability to **reassign the `this` pointer** was deprecated.

Comment: But why? Looking for a technical answer

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: Because it makes no sense to re-assign the `this` pointer, which would lead to incredibly error-prone code. `this` should lead to the "current object instance" within a member function, and never anything else.

Answer (score 6):

You misinterpreted the quote.

> Early versions of C++ would let the this pointer be changed; by doing so a programmer could change which object a method was working on. This feature was eventually deprecated, and now this in C++ is `const`.

What's deprecated is `this` — the pointer, not the object it points to — being mutable.

`this` itself is still very much alive, with the type `prvalue T*`. (GCC simulates this for the time being, by making `this` a `rvalue T* const` in current GCC 4.7.0.)

Comment: well, the article is phrased badly too

Comment: Isn't `this` const only in const member functions?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: No. The **pointer** is const, always. Remember `T* const` is _not_ the same as `T const*`.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus - It's still not an l-value though even in non-const member functions.

Comment: What I meant: "In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword `this` is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called. The type of `this` in a member function of a class X is `X*`. If the member function is declared `const`, the type of this is `const X*`, if the member function is declared volatile, the type of `this` is `volatile X*`, and if the member function is declared `const volatile`, the type of this is `const volatile X*`."

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Which standard is that? My cursory checks indicate that within both a non-`const` member function and the class constructor, `this` has type `T const*`.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Hmm same wording in 2003, too. Does my g++ (GCC) 4.7.0 20110731 (experimental) _and_ Wikipedia have a bug, then?

Comment: FWIW clang says `this` is "an rvalue of type `X *`"

Comment: I agree with @CatPlusPlus. `this` is a _prvalue_. It has a pointer type, i.e. non-class type, so it _can't_ be cv-qualified. The type of `this` in a non-const member function of T is `T*`, not `T* const`. The fact that you can't change it is because it is a _prvalue_, not because it is `const` which it isn't.

Comment: @Charles: Perhaps GCC is using `const` to simulate that feature for the time being, then. And are you suggesting that `int* const` is not a valid type?

Comment: `int* const` is a valid type for an _lvalue_.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Perhaps, in a similar way that it uses `X&` for function arguments that are _lvalues_ when it prints error messages about function overloads or template argument deductions.

Comment: For reference, 3/10/4: "Class prvalues can have cv-qualified types; non-class prvalues always have cv-unqualified types."

Answer (score 6):

Based on your edit, the Wikipedia article is poorly worded. `this` is not deprecated, just that the feature to allow `this` pointer to be changed has been deprecated. The keyword `this` still exists.

From [Stroustrup himself](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#this):

**Why is "this" not a reference?**

> Because "this" was introduced into C++ (really into C with Classes)
>   before references were added. Also, I chose "this" to follow Simula
>   usage, rather than the (later) Smalltalk use of "self".

Comment: It's phrased just fine. The OP simply misinterpreted it.

Comment: This is the only answer that explains what the OP misunderstood. +1.

Comment: @ereOn: In what way does mine not?